# How to fix a stretched image in Android Camera API?

Tags: android

I am getting stretched preview of image I want to fix it to portrait even after rotation of camera it is fixed to portrait. I am using the following code.

```
private TextureView mTextureView;
private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            setupCamera(width, height);
            connectCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    };
```

**Setup**

```
private void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for(String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()){
                CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                if(cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) ==
                        CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT){
                    continue;
                }
                StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                int deviceOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                mTotalRotation = sensorToDeviceRotation(cameraCharacteristics, deviceOrientation);
                boolean swapRotation = mTotalRotation == 90 || mTotalRotation == 270;
                int rotatedWidth = width;
                int rotatedHeight = height;
                if(swapRotation) {
                    rotatedWidth = height;
                    rotatedHeight = width;
                }
                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);
                mVideoSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);
                mImageSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);
                mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mImageSize.getWidth(), mImageSize.getHeight(), ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
                mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                mCameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**For the Preview**

```
private void startPreview(){
    SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
    surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
    Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

    try {
        mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
        mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        mPreviewCaptureSession = session;
                        try {
                            mPreviewCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),
                                    null, mBackgroundHandler);
                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Unable to setup camera preview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: To add code here, paste in your code and click the 'code' button, so it formats correctly. There is a preview window so you can see what your post will look like before you publish it.